# PHP Automatically adding whitespaces

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an API in PHP with PDO. All of my queries on my laptop itself work fine, but the moment i test it on a different pc, some methods don't. I am using the exact same version of xampp so I find it out. I echoed out the query and it looks like this :

*Edit~ As Per Suggestion, I have turned it into `AND`*

```php
SELECT*FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id=: record_id AND tabelnaam=: tabelnaam
```

This happens for every pc and also my laptop. Though on my laptop it functions fine^

The section where all of this happens is underneath :

```php
$base_query = "SELECT * FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id = :record_id AND tabelnaam = :tabelnaam";

            echo $base_query;
            $qry = $this->CONN->prepare($base_query);
            $qry->bindParam(":record_id", $record_id);
            $qry->bindParam(":tabelnaam", $tabelnaam);
            $qry->execute();




            if ($qry->rowCount() == 0) {
                http_response_code(404);
                print_r(json_encode(["message" => "No Results Found"]));
                return;
            }

            $response = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I'm not particularly sure why it does this, but it's effecting the other pcs

Result on my laptop returns :

```php
SELECT*FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id=: record_id AND tabelnaam=: tabelnaam[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "img_url": "image0-1708893712681.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "img_url": "image1-1708893712685.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "img_url": "image2-1708893712686.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "img_url": "image3-1708893712698.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "img_url": "image0-1709673514264.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "img_url": "image0-1709673523113.png",
        "record_id": 1,
        "tabelnaam": "product"
    }
]
```

While on other pcs it returns :

```php
SELECT*FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id=: record_id AND tabelnaam=: tabelnaam
    {'message':'No Results Found'}
```

Comment: `&&` should not be used for mysql, use `AND`.

Comment: PHP would never do this. You're going to need to look at what else is interacting with your code/connections.

Comment: @user3783243, I have changed it to ```AND```, but to no avail. As far as i'm aware, there's nothing more that could be interacting with this section of the code

Comment: Put `$base_query = "SELECT * FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id = :record_id AND tabelnaam = :tabelnaam";
echo $base_query;` in a stand alone script. Do you get spacing?

Comment: So you're saying that `echo $base_query;` outputs `SELECT*FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id=: record_id AND tabelnaam=: tabelnaam` instead of `SELECT * FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id=: record_id AND tabelnaam=: tabelnaam` ...is that right? It wasn't 100% clear what the issue was, from your question - or how those JSON results are relevant, in that case. If so, then surely it's _removing_ whitespace which is the issue, not adding it? Or have I misunderstood something. The description doesn't seem to match the stated output, and as others have said, a simple `echo` can't mangle it like that

Comment: @ADyson Yes, when echoing ```$base_query``` it shows that which is not what it should be doing.

Comment: Are you echoing to the command-line? To a web page? The context _could_ be significant. I have to say I can't reproduce anything like it. Are you quite certain the code and info you've provided us makes a [mre] of the issue? Without one it's very hard to diagnose anything

Comment: Definitely not enough to be reproduced. You are indeed correct. I have solved the issue and it's something outside of what was given. For Context the api is built using FastRoute. Therefore there's this one file I have with all the endpoints, controllers and methods. I never thought about it since I thought, oh. Everything is working fine on my laptop so surely it's correct. After attempting to just insert the variables I got a genuine MySQL Error. After checking the variables, it turns out that I had switched the order of the params of the endpoint and the params of the function. Works now

Comment: While it does work now, it really makes me wonder why it worked on my laptop, but not on any other device. Everything was being tested locally so it never effected me until yesterday when it was put on a server and had clients accessing it.

Comment: Sounds like you laptop configuration is not the same as your other systems. I'd look at recreating that so it behaves the same. Always an issue when you test on a different system than production runs.